# How to put one div on the left and two divs vertically on its right

Tags: html, css

I have a very classical layout I achieve quite often, and I'm always improvising on how I can do it. I separated the three divs on the picture (red lines). My issue is always with the right bottom one: even if I fix the size of the left Div, I put the top div as float:right. I still have to cheat for the problematic div and play with negative margins.

For this example, it is quite easy since the two divs (left and top) have fixed sizes, but I'd like to have a pattern for responsive flexible layouts.

I already searched the web, it seams each person has his own solution, but I'm not finding any clear clean tasty solution.

any ideas?

[image: three divs, two vertical on the right]

The expected behavior is :

1. no fixed sizes, actually, no sizing at all (let the elements take the place they need)
2. if there is space left on the right, don't go to a new line.
3. if there is no more space, jump to a new line but go completely to the left (as expected with `display:inline-block`)

Here is a jsfiddle sample:

even if there is plenty of room (in width) for the div with `id='2'`, it jumps to a new line (because `display:inline-block` tries to append that div to the right of `id='2'` and when it doesn't find, it goes to a new line instead of going to the right of `id='1'`)

http://jsfiddle.net/zhamdi/zu5sU/6/

I know there are js grids to to do that like
http://gridster.net/

But I don't want something to drag and drop, just a simple adaptable layout

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a link to that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you put the two right `div`s in another containing `div`, wouldn't that solve your problem? (We really need code, preferably jsFiddle, to know what your problem is exactly)

Comment: Sometimes there are multiple possible ways of achieving something. Just pick one.

Comment: Hi @myfunkyside Naturally, the idea is : if there is space left vertically, don't go to a new line. Exactly the same behavior (that works by default if the two vertical divs were on the left: when you say 'display: inline-block', things come to the right if there is space

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do that is to use a column layout.

You would put both sections in their own containing divs:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A23s4/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="content one">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="content two">
        </div>
        <div class="content two alt">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.column{
    float: left;
}
.content{
    width: 100px;
}
.content.one{
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.content.two{
    height: 100px;
    background:blue;
}
.content.two.alt{
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, but you're using fixed sizes, I want something with the percentages: if there is space on the right, I don't want the div to go to a new line, but without fixed sizes

Comment: @ZiedHamdi please also note that I'm just showing the least amount of code to get the point across.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really expressing my self badly: I don't want to give any size, I want the elements to take what they need

Comment: You're expressing yourself fine. You're just not grasping the concept. You would have to define widths at some point http://jsfiddle.net/A23s4/2/

Comment: :-), I've just edited my question, here is a jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/zhamdi/zu5sU/

Comment: You're forcing a width everywhere, I want it just to get the width it wants. For example, you can have an image on the left, you can't use a percent width, you will have to use pixles there, then you have those other divs 2 and 3 that you want to adapt to the screen size

Comment: You're also forcing the width. In your JSfiddle you put a set width on the main container.

Comment: yes sure, that's just to show the typical case (to simulate a screen size), if I remove the width from the example, there 's nothing to see: all of them are on one line :)

Comment: width 100% should always work. You're going to have to assign a width somewhere buddy. http://jsfiddle.net/zu5sU/4/

Comment: Actually let's suppose we have a fixed with for 1 (because of an image and a predictable size, as in this example), I want the divs, 2 and 3, to take the remaining space. but one below the other (2 and 3 have to take all the remainig width). If 2 becomes too high for 3 to be below it, 3 will jump to the next line

Comment: I updated my fiddle, there's actually no more widhts apart for the left column. As you see, the id=3 goes to a new line, even if there's plenty of space
http://jsfiddle.net/zhamdi/zu5sU/6/

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Yea, I was confused because the layout in that fiddle is definitely not the same as the layout in the image you provided.

Comment: @ZiedHamdi 2 different layouts. 2 different ways of styling.

Comment: As I stated in the question, The layout in the image is done by cheating with a negative margin, it is also possible because the divs 1 and 2 are almost of fixed size. This situation happened to me quite often, and I always end up paying the big price for these cheating techniques (I'm not a designer, I just try my best with css and what I've read from design books). So I thought there might be a  solution I didn't know about. Someone unvoted the question, so my chances of getting a clear answer are decreasing :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, if I say a clear answer, it's really an answer to this issue of every div that can have its own constraints (for example let's say div 1 is fixed, how to do for the two others to be in that layout?)