# is it possible to have a relative display:inline-block

Tags: css

I didn't know how to adress this issue before, and after discussions and questions like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292866/how-to-put-one-div-on-the-left-and-two-divs-vertically-on-its-right), I have a clear idea of what is the exact wanted feature (I don't want to reuse the old question since it is polluted with answers to my bad question :)

So here is the question:

```
display:inline-block
```

permits if we have space on the right to append the element newt to it, and if there is no space, to get back to a new line.

My question is: could it come back to a relative new line? that means

- if there is space left below the line it is in, use that space
- if there is no more space, go to a new line
- the same applies if the second line is full, jump to the third line still next to the element on the left if there is space
- have this in cascade mode

here's a jsfiddle to explain the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/zhamdi/zu5sU/6/

Comment: 1) You should give a bounty in order to get an answer you like. 2) Edit the previous question.

Comment: the previous question was downvoted because badly asked, It seams to be a completely different question after I rethought it

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you're asking.. when you say line, do you maybe mean a column of sort?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a basic 'refinement of a previous question which should have been edited instead of re-posted. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292866/how-to-put-one-div-on-the-left-and-two-divs-vertically-on-its-right

Comment: It is not a refinement, it's kind of the difference between "do you smoke" and "do you have cancer" it's different event if it emerged from the same issue.
You can look at how this one is voted and the other one is downvoted

Comment: Yes @webkit the concept is between a column and a row: it's about filling the empty spaces mainly. As visible in the jsfiddle example: there's plenty of space under the row that is filled horizontally, but the new div jumps far away under it: I needed this behavior many times for my app, and I was doing mind gymnastics to find a way (always for this same pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't just wrap the right hand-side in an extra div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="1" class="left"> left one this is where it gets tricky, look there is plenty of space to the right, but instead of taking it, the div id=3 is coming below me. stupid one! :)
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div id="2" class="one"> right takes as much place as it wants lkjml mlkj mlk mlkj mlkj mlkjmkjm ilm lkjml jmijom llkj mkjmjmij lj
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="two"> this one also, if there is no more room, it jumps to the next line under left
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{

}

.left{
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
}

.one{
    background:blue;
}
.two{
    background:green;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yes, if the div id=3 is too large, it will remain on the right instead of taking back his place from the start of the page: imagine you have a short text for id=1.

Comment: You can play by making shorter the text of id=1, and/or longer the text of id=3. Here emerges another question: when do we jump to a new line? is is when we reach some percentage like 10% too high for id=3, or as soon as id=3 is higher, etc...
I think this feature is not supported by browsers natively??

Comment: See the problem is that `inline-block` is relative to the container, not to the elements within the container... so the "wrap-to-next-line" behavior is based on the width of all 3 inner divs. And the "line" which wraps is based on the max height of the largest div on that line.

Comment: Exactly, see!!! inline-block is relative to the container, this might not be an issue from the moment we could add kind of a "relative-to" attribute.
maybe it would be better than a new css display="tile" option since "relative-to" says where to stop inlining...

Comment: Also if we add a "relative-to" attribute, this won't suffice because we have to say from which height excess we have to jump below the element on the left (there could be cases where 50% of extra height is ok on the right, and cases where 10% is already too much)